# Why is an IEnumerable(or IList) implemented using arrays instead of Linked Lists?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, ienumerable

I was reading basic tutorials on implementing the methods of the interface IENumerable and found out that all examples use arrays. I was under the impression that an IENumerable is essentially very similar to a linked list. And I am fairly confident that an array and a linked list are two completely different data structures.

So then why is one (a linked list) being implemented using the other (an array) when we actually argue that they are quite different?

This is how the code looks like on MSDN page:

```
// Collection of Person objects. This class 
// implements IEnumerable so that it can be used 
// with ForEach syntax. 
public class People : IEnumerable
{
    private Person[] _people;
    public People(Person[] pArray)
    {
        _people = new Person[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _people[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }

// Implementation for the GetEnumerator method.
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
    }

    public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PeopleEnum(_people);
    }
}
```

Is there an implementation of IENumerable that I have missed?

Edit: I now understand that IENumerable doesn't necessarily resemble a linked list. However, this code from MSDN implements an IList using an array:

```
class SimpleList : IList
{
    private object[] _contents = new object[8];
    private int _count;

    public SimpleList()
    {
        _count = 0;
    }

    // IList Members 
    public int Add(object value)
    {
        if (_count < _contents.Length)
        {
            _contents[_count] = value;
            _count++;

            return (_count - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
//etc...
}
```

Comment: You can implement `IEnumerable` any way you want, array just happens to be very convenient for that purpose.

Comment: But isn't it conceptually wrong since arrays != linked lists?

Comment: `LinkedList<T>` implements `IEnumerable` as does `System.Array`, you seem to be confused about the purpose of interfaces.

Comment: You may benefit from reading about _interfaces_, of which `IEnumerable` is one. There are _lots_ of ways to implement `IEnumerable`. Arrays, linked lists, reading from a file, incrementing a counter, picking numbers at random, the only thing that's required is to return an instance of `IEnumerator`, which in turn must implement the `MoveNext()` method and `Current` property.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot IENumerable being implemented by `LinkedList<T>` and `Array` in two separate implementations makes sense. But an array being used to implement a linked list in the same implementation is where i am having trouble. Linked list is dynamic. Arrays are not. Doesn't using arrays in implementing a linked list kind of data structure essentially killing the dynamic nature of a linked list? Shouldn't they be separate? I am just thinking very basic DS here.

Comment: Implementing `IEnumerable` in no way indicates that you are providing a linked list.

Comment: how about the example in this link? they implement an `IList` using an array once again. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: IList is still just an interface that promises a construct you can add or remove elements to + IEnumerable interface etc... Just because it ends on List doesn't mean linked list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was under the impression that an IENumerable is essentially very
>   similar to a linked list.

I'm not really sure where you got that impression. An object implementing `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` means *"this object exposes an enumerator, which makes it iteratable"*, it has nothing to do directly to an implementation of a linked list, or an array. They *do* both share the common feature of being iteratable. It is a binding contract to the caller.

> So then why is one (a linked list) being implemented using the other
>   (an array) when we actually argue that they are quite different?

A linked list can have an array as it's storage as an *implementation detail*, though that would definitely be a poor design choice.

You may note that `List<T>` also uses an array as it's internal storage, which it re-sizes once it hits the maximum size of the internal array.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I just wrote an implementation that uses something similar to a LinkedListNode instead of an array but is lacking some things like the constructor with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` are not linked lists. They are interfaces that provide access to enumeration.

Think of it this way: IEnumerable is a promise to deliver 0-n values on enumeration (for example by using `foreach`).

Many real classes can fulfill this promise. Lists do, arrays do, collections of all kinds do, your own classes may if you program them to do so. How you get stuff *into* or *out of* your container is container specific, `IEnumerable` only says something about how to get data *from* your container to do something with it.

That's a very easy explanation, you may want to read about *deferred execution* later when you got this concept down.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: `IEnumerable` is "similar to" a linked list only in that it defines a sequence of values. But a sequence of values can be defined in any number of other ways as well, including as an array.

The `IEnumerable` type is an [*interface*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx). It dictates only what something must expose publicly; it doesn't in any specific way dictate what the *implementation* should be.

In the case of [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), the only thing something that implements that interface must do is implement a method named `GetEnumerator()`, which must return an instance of another interface, [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx). That interface must in turn implement a property named `Current`, which returns an instance of `object`, and a method named `MoveNext()` which informs the `IEnumerator` object to select the next item in the enumeration.

(The interface also requires implementation of a `Reset()` method, but many implementations of the interface just throw `NotSupportedException` for that method…the `Current` and `MoveNext()` members are the minimum to make a useful implementation of the interface).

The enumeration can be implemented in whatever manner is suitable for the object implementing it. The `System.Linq.Enumerable` type even includes implementations that simply repeat the same value some number of times, or which emits a sequence of integers. *None* of the members of that type store an enumeration per se; they either create one from scratch, or transform some existing one.

Likewise, you could enumerate lines of text in a file, or pick numbers at random, or reverse the elements of an array. The only thing that matters is that you have some mechanism to choose a sequence of values.

The example you posted doesn't actually show us the implementation of `IEnumerator`…there's some unknown class named `PeopleEnum` that handles the enumeration. Presumably, this class simply stores an index into the array of the object passed to it, returning each element in sequence (it could also be implemented using an ["iterator method"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx), but it wouldn't need a whole other type to accomplish that, so I'm guessing it wasn't).

I hope the above helps more than confuses. :)